# Redux saga not calling the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to use redux-saga to call my API and passing it a parameter. I am using `redux-logger` and `console.log()` to debug. But it seems that my saga doesn't go call the API for some reason.

Here is the console log of the states... as you can see the `apiMsg` doesnt change, however I have it change for each action.

[image]

I think I am going wrong somewhere in the actions, reducer or the component. Or else I am calling the API wrong in the Saga.

This is my code

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getPostApi(postId){
  return axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`
  ).then(
    response => {
      return response;
    }
  ).catch(
    err => {throw err;}
  );
}
```

my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../Reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const logger = createLogger();
  return {
    ...createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger)),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run
  }
}
```

the saga

```
import {call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as service from '../Services/api';
import * as actions from '../Actions';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export function* fetchPost(action){
  try{
    yield put(actions.apiRequest());
    const [post] = yield [call(service.getPostApi, action.postId)];
    yield put(actions.apiRequestSucceeded(post));
  } catch(e){
    yield put(actions.apiRequestFailed());
  }
}

export function* watchApiRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(types.FETCH_POST, fetchPost);
}
```

actions

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export const fetchPost = (postId) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_POST,
  postId,
});

export const apiRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: types.API_REQUEST
  }
}

export const apiRequestSucceeded = (post) => {
  return {
    type: types.API_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED,
    post
  }
}

export const apiRequestFailed = () => {
  return {
    type: types.API_REQUEST_FAILED
  }
}
```

reducer

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  apiMsg: '',
  postId: 1,
  fetching: false,
  post: null
};

export default function getPostData(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.API_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        apiMsg: 'API call request!',
        fetching: true
      }
    case types.API_REQUEST_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        apiMsg: 'API called succeeded!',     
        fetching: false,
        postId: action.post.id,
        post: action.title
      };
    case types.API_REQUEST_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        apiMsg: 'API called failed!',
        fetching: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the component page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPost} from './Actions/apiTesterActions';

class TestPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPost(1)
  }

   render() {
    const { postId, fetching, post } = this.props;
    console.log('Test page props', postId, fetching, post);
    return (
      <View> 
        <Text>Test Page Works! </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    postId: state.getPostData.postId,
    fetching: state.getPostData.fetching,
    post: state.getPostData.post
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPost})(TestPage);
```

I am still learning Redux, and now redux-saga, so I don't fully understand the structure/hierarchy, but I am learning and any advice is helpful. Thank you

**EDIT:**
I am using this [redux saga api call example](https://github.com/jinhoyim/react-redux-saga-ajax-tutorial/tree/master/src) as a guide.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './ReduxTest/Store/configureStore';
import rootSaga from './ReduxTest/sagas';

const store = configureStore();
store.runSaga(rootSaga)

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

saga/index.js

```
import {fork, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {watchApiRequest} from './apiTester';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all [
    fork(watchApiRequest)
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong here. But you can surely follow Saga examples from https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples. This will definitely help you.

Can you add codesandBox for this?

Comment: I followed most their examples. I still cannot find the problem. The main problem is that Redux is new to me, I am starting to understand it, but once I moved to redux-saga middleware it got more confusing.

Comment: Is the `postId` present in the final request's URL that you log in the console?

Comment: @PaoloGuerra For detail, Im following this https://github.com/jinhoyim/react-redux-saga-ajax-tutorial/tree/master/src ... I changed the values, still same result

Comment: You export `configureStore`, but where is it used? You have to call `sagaMiddleware.run(watchApiRequest)` somewhere. If the `run` function is not called, no saga will be watching your actions.

Comment: its in my index.js `const store = configureStore();
store.runSaga(rootSaga)`

Comment: Add the index.js code to the question, please.

Comment: Done, the index.js goes to `<App />` which hasnt got any redux, but only directs to `<TestPage />` for testing

Comment: Why are you using the literal string `"FETCH_POST"` instead of `types.FETCH_POST` in your saga? This could cause the error if `types.FETCH_POST` actually is a different string, like for example `posts/FETCH_POST`.

Comment: Yeah, i thought the same, I changed it to `types.FETCH_POST`, but this didn't help.

Comment: Where do you define `rootSaga` that you use in index.js? You don't have a default export in the saga code. Should `watchApiRequest` be the default export?

Comment: I've added an answer, it seemed to be a syntax mistake. Instead of `yield all [...]` it should be `yield all ([...])` in saga/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time with a lot of debugging, I have figured the problem.

When I first started creating the application, I got the following error...

> [...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code

As the `yield all [...]` was deprecated, I changed my code without taking it into consideration, I was happy the error went, but didn't realize how much of an impact it would have on my application.

**(wrong)** saga/index.js

```
import {fork, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {watchApiRequest} from './apiTester';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all [
    fork(watchApiRequest)
  ]
}
```

**(right)** saga/index.js

```
import {fork, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {watchApiRequest} from './apiTester';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all ([
    fork(watchApiRequest)
  ])
}
```

As You can see it needed to be wrapped in brackets `yield all ([...])`
You will get the deprecated error but your code will still work. I am unsure how to fix the deprecated error.

If someone knows how to get rid of the deprecated error than that would great.